# Identification of the transformer based on the datasheet

Tags: transformer, identification

I am currently developing a battery-powered system designed to activate an LED bar in the absence of AC power. I came across an IC, specifically the PN6370PSSC-R1B, which appears to be suitable for my project. However, I am faced with the challenge of identifying the transformer used in the application circuit, as the datasheet does not provide any information about it. Here is the application circuit for the mentioned IC:
[image]

I would appreciate the help !

Comment: You probably need to get it custom made. Have you tried contacting the manufacturer?

Comment: This could help ? https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/%E9%87%8D%E7%A3%85%E6%9D%A5%E8%A2%AD%E4%B8%93%E6%94%BB%E5%8D%B0%E5%BA%A6%E5%B8%82%E5%9C%BA%E4%B8%8D%E9%87%8D%E5%90%AF%E7%9A%84%E5%B8%82%E7%94%B5%E4%BF%9D%E6%8A%A412v1a%E7%94%B5%E6%BA%90%E6%96%B9%E6%A1%88-lynn-liu

Comment: Something like this could not be used https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucc28750.pdf?ts=1707742274074&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fpower-management%252Facdc-isolated-dcdc-switching-regulators%252Fflyback-controllers%252Fproducts.html

Comment: How can this IC help in absence of AC power?

Comment: @winny i already but they still didn't respond

Comment: @Antonio51 it does help , thank you so much ! i will review the datasheet of that TI component

Comment: For high volume mass production, a custom wind is your best option. For low volume, there are PI and TI ICs with recommended COTS parts from Coilcraft, Wurth and the like.